# Julia @btime cannot find internal function

Tags: julia, benchmarking

I'm wondering if I found a bug in Julia's `BenchmarkTools` or if there's something deeper happening here that I don't understand. Running the following script

```
function test()
    function func1(n)
        sum(1:n)
    end
    function func2(n)
        ans = 0
        for i = 1:n
            ans += i
        end
        return ans
    end
    @time func1(100000)
    @time func2(100000)
end
```

works exactly as expected and times both functions. However, using `@btime` instead of `@time` gives me an undefined error:

> ERROR: UndefVarError: func1 not defined

If I move the internal functions outside `test()`, both timing versions work fine, but in my actual tests this is not something I can easily do. I prefer using `@btime` to `@time`, as it's more accurate and robust, but here I clearly can't. Can someone explain if this is a bug or what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `$` to your `@btime` calls:

```
function test()
    function func1(n)
        sum(1:n)
    end
    function func2(n)
        ans = 0
        for i = 1:n
            ans += i
        end
        return ans
    end
    @btime $func1(100000)
    @btime $func2(100000)
end
```

This interpolates the function definition and now the inner function will be visible to the benchmark.

Comment: I had to also add `$` to my inputs as well to get my tests working. Could you perhaps explain further what interpolating a function definition means? I've never seen this idea before.

Comment: I am not 100% sure (this functionality is totally undocumented)  but I would assume that interpolating forces `func1` and `func2` to be created so they get compiled before the rest of the `test` function code and then gen be seen by `@btime`